# Wrap the title attributes

Tags: jquery

I have tried to wrap the title attribute which is replacement for another title value(string).

Here is the jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/8yjwm9e7/7/

Jquery

```
var Ntitle = '2343245353/n42343243243/n8345882323';
$('#titlea').prop('title', Ntitle);
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
<td id="titlea" title="phoneNumber">Phone Numbers</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: change .prop to **.attr**

Comment: var Ntitle = '2343245353/n42343243243/n8345882323';
$('#titlea').attr('title', Ntitle);

Comment: The demo works fine; what is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#titlea').attr('title', Ntitle);
```

must work

.prop() -> use for properties

.attr() -> use for attributes

Comment: why are you adding `.html()`?

Comment: i understand that, i was wondering why you wanted to change the innerHTML of the element when the OP just wanted to change the title attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes for strings and backslash for special characters like `\n`, `\t` and others.

```
var Ntitle = "2343245353\n42343243243\n8345882323";
$('#titlea').attr('title', Ntitle);
```